# remap to part of message

Tags: ros, remap, topics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I have written my first node - a Quaternion to euler conversion node (using the tf library). The node subscribes to geometry_msgs::Quaternion and publishes geometry_msgs::Vector3.

I now want to connect this node to the quaternion part of a pose message that's published by another node.

So i used this command:

```
rosrun mypkg quat_to_euler_conv quaternion:=ground_truth/pose/orientation
```

because pose/orientation is of type geometry_msgs::Quaternion i think this should work. but it doesn't connect. using rostopic echo and pub i can make the node work fine though.

Is it maybe not possible to remap a topic to a message part of another topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237633/remap-to-part-of-message/) by [Orangelynx](https://answers.ros.org/users/27234/orangelynx/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-06-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use toopic_tools:
http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/transform

---

Originally posted by [AA](https://answers.ros.org/users/29529/aa/) with karma: 26 on 2017-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-17**:
To add to the answer of @AA:

> Is it maybe not possible to remap a topic to a message part of another topic?

No, that is not possible. `rostopic` uses some tricks internally to allow this, but the regular remapping infrastructure does not support remapping parts of msgs.